# How to create a directory in node js using fs.mkdir?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, filesystems, mkdir

Here I am trying to create a directory using async function fs.mkdir using the below code but I am getting a error

```
ERROR: No such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\tmp\test';

var fs = require("fs");
console.log("Going to create directory /tmp/test");
fs.mkdir('/tmp/test',function(err){
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
console.log("Directory created successfully!");
});
```

Any Help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This error could happen if, for instance, the directory "/tmp" does not exist.
If this is the case, you need before create "/tmp" and after "/tmp/test".

There is a package [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) that can help you:

So, the code will be:

```
    var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

    mkdirp('/tmp/test', function (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err)
        else console.log('Done!')
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try make a directory tmp in the same path as the script and it should work, else you must write the full path. If the tmp directory doesn't exist you must make that first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fs.mkdirSync and also check if the directory exists or not.

```
var checkIfDirectoryExists = function(dirPath, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    try {
        // Query the entry
        var stats = fs.lstatSync(dirPath);
        // Is it a directory?
        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            successCallback();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        errorCallback();
    }
};

var mkdirIfNotExists = function(dirPath) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        checkIfDirectoryExists(dirPath, function() {
            resolve();
        }, function() {
            fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
            resolve();
        });
    });
};
```